# Conditional If-Else List Comprehension in Coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

Is there a way to do this in one line of coffeescript using a list comprehension?

```
  len = 70
  msgsFormatted = []
  for msg in messages
      if msg.length == len
      then msgsFormatted.push(msg + ' ...')
      else msgsFormatted.push msg
```

I was attempting this but it wouldn't transpile

```
msgsFormatted = (msg + ' ...' if msg.length == len else msg for msg in messages)
```

I also tried this but it was clearly not compiling to the right javascript

```
msgsFormatted = (if msg.length == len then msg + ' ...' else msg for msg in messages)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List comprehension doesn't offer else, but you could use a conditional statement within that:

```
len = 2
messages = [1, 2, 3, 4, '22', 5]
alert ((if msg.length == len then msg + ' ...' else msg) for msg in messages)
```

Try yourself: https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

Use "Mapping Arrays" like

```
messages = [ "Peter", "Paul", "Mary" ]

len = 5     
msgsFormatted = []

msgsFormatted = messages.map (msg) -> (if msg.length == len then msg + ' ...' else msg)

console.log msgsFormatted
```

Comment: Or you could `format = (msg) -> if msg.length ....` and then `messages = (format(msg) for msg in messages)`.